# page.click() i'ts not working properly in an <a href> tag

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Working on a grid (table) that some columns have a text that is actually a link to the detail of something using a `<a href="url">` tag.

Using `await page.click(my_target);` was working perfectly for my main tables but in this case, the click event doesn't do anything:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>
            <a ng-show="true" href="/edit/001">Some text</a>
        </tr></td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click event on puppeteer can work in unexpected ways.

The problem came when the text stacks in two lines, so accordingly to the documentation of puppeteer the click works: "*This method fetches an element with selector, scrolls it into view if needed, and then uses page.mouse **to click in the center of the element**. If there's no element matching selector, the method throws an error.*"

Behavior in each case would be something like this:

[image: one line grid click]
[image: two lines grid click]

If you can see our click will point to the center and for the second picture it wouldn't reach the text/link. So you can use an element selector following a click event:

```
await page.$eval(my_target, element => element.click());
```

Comment: Feel free to post a better way to handle this scenario.

Comment: You can try making link `display: block`